# How to differ between System variable and Custom variable

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, reflection

I have a class like below:-

```
public Class Student
{
  string Name {get; set;}
  int Age {get; set;}
  Address studentAddres {get; set;}
}

public class Address
{
 string Street{get; set;}
 string City {get; set;}
}
```

Here **Name and Age** are **System Define type** and **StudentAddres** is **custom type**. How to differentiate between them using code.
I am using Reflection but not able to achieve.

Comment: can I ask why? I'd imagine you need to look into namespaces

Comment: Try out smth like this `string variable = ""; variable.GetType().Assembly.GetName().FullName.CompareTo("mscorlib");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you want to see either a value type or a string. Then you can use: 
[Type.IsPrimitive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.isprimitive.aspx) property

> Gets a value indicating whether the Type is one of the primitive
>   types.
>
> The primitive types are Boolean, Byte, SByte, Int16, UInt16, Int32,
>   UInt32, Int64, UInt64, IntPtr, UIntPtr, Char, Double, and Single.

```
int i = 10;
string str = "";
var isPrimitive = i.GetType().IsValueType || i is string; // returns true since i is value type
var isPrimitiveWithString = str.GetType().IsValueType || str is string; 
 // returns true

CustomClass obj = new CustomClass();
var isPrimitive3 = obj.GetType().IsPrimitive; // returns false
```

Answer (score 2):

```
if (SomeObject.GetType().Assembly != typeof(int).Assembly)
{
    //SomeObject is defined as part of my program
}
else
{
    //SomeObject is a standard .Net type
}
```